# Use of cached hash value to speed up equality tests

Tags: oop, hashcode, equality

My target language is C++, but this is a question over object oriented programming in general.

Suppose I have a class for which testing equality takes a non-trivial amount of time, but I also have a hash value that I have computed over it. I can rely on the data to stay the same for the life of the object.

Is it common practice to cache the hash value, and use that to test for inequality?

To make this example more concrete, I have a class that contains a potentially long list of 2D locations, and I expect to make many many equality comparisons over it. I create the hash value upon construction by mixing the hashes of all of the locations.

When testing for equality, I check the hash values first. If the hashes are equal, I do the exhaustive, point-by-point equality test. Otherwise I call them unequal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds good to me as long as your hash algorithm is guaranteed to produce the same hash for the same input data.  Then your check should speed things up considerably at the small cost of extra memory of storing the hash value (and a 1 time cost of computing the hash)

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to say, "If the hashes are *unequal*, I do the exhaustive, point-by-point equality test."

In any case -- yes, you've got a good idea, this is a perfectly reasonable design. You're trading a bit of cheap storage for a chunk of expensive CPU and/or wall time. A design like this can give enormous performance benefits. For example, consider the case where each individual point test requires a database query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

If the two objects produce unequal hashes, then they should be unequal.

Comment: Right -- so if the hashes are equal, then you know you can skip all the point-by-point checks. Correct?

Comment: Two objects containing the same data can be relied upon to yield the same hash value, but the opposite is not true; objects with different data can yield the same hash value (sometimes called a hash collision). So, if the hash values are different, I can be certain that I have objects with different data. If they are the same, I can't be entirely sure that they have the same data, so I have to do a deeper check.

Comment: "objects with different data can yield the same hash value" In theory. In practice, if you're writing code to explicitly handle an unexpected hash collision then you're wasting your time and/or using a bad hash algorithm.

Comment: " if you're writing code to explicitly handle an unexpected hash collision..." I agree in the sense that you should always expect a hash collision. Robust code should be able to handle even very rare occurrences. In my case, I might expect a number of unique objects that is significant with respect to 2^32, meaning a hash in uint32 units is effectively guaranteed to produce collisions, regardless of how well-formed the hash algorithm is.

Comment: "you should always expect a hash collision." What? No. You're missing the point of hashing then. "meaning a hash in uint32 units is effectively guaranteed to produce collisions" That's what I meant about a bad hash algorithm - don't use one that has a 32 bit output, that's silly. Your app doesn't use hashing for cryptographic purposes, you're just detecting changes. SHA1 is more than sufficient to trust that you'll never accidentally get a collision.

Comment: I'm sorry that you're so upset. I could have been more clear: I'm talking about hash sets and tables, not security hashing. Here, a bad hash is one that takes a significant amount of time and requires me to store more data than I have to.